# React Native Redux

Tags: react-native

I need your help!
I am making e-commerce react-native app with redux.
It has list of user addresses, when user click to edit or add new address, it opens inputs and button to another screen, where user can select address on map.

The problem I faced that I should get addresses from my Api (from server) and also, I need to use google api for geocoding - getting street name based on selected location (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode). When I try to get data from both Apis my state breaking. Can you suggest me, how correctly to use apis together?

Comment: Hi Oleg! Welcome to SO :) 
Can you post some of your code and errors you are getting to get an idea what exactly is breaking?

Comment: Thank you! I found solution for this issue. Separated into 2 reducers